# Cholesterol's role in lipid uptake

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, metabolism, fat-metabolism

I'm studying the digestion of fats and I understand that our dietary fats mostly consist of triglycerides. We absorb the fats and eventually they end up in a muscle/adipose cell for storage (as triglycerides) or for oxidation for energy.

However I don't understand exactly where cholesterol plays in? I read about lipids being synthesized by the liver being exported by VLDL and then taken up by cells. We're moving closer to cholesterol here but I still don't see the connection.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Are you asking about the role of cholesterol in cells in general, or its function in lipoproteins, specifially in VLDL, or ... ?